# Console shared with Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, console

I have simple problems with MT in java. I woudlike to synchronize acces to console. An example:
first thread write in System.out "Number one" Thread2 printl("Number two"). I woud like to synchronize this thread writing sequentially numer in console without buffering. How do this?

```
Thread one
Thread two
Thread one
Thread two
...
```

//Code

```
package com.example;

public class MyThread implements Runnable{


@Override
synchronized public void run(){
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Thread first");

    }
}
```

}

//

```
package com.example;

public class MyThread2 implements Runnable {


@Override
synchronized public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("");

}

}
```

//

```
 package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Thread th1= new Thread(new MyThread());
Thread th2= new Thread(new MyThread2());

th2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
th1.start();
th2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're having problems with existing code, please post some of it.  What have you tried so far?  Also, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this besides [tag:Homework], or some sort of learning exercise.  If this is homework, please add that tag to the question too, so we know to just give hints.

Comment: Why use threads if you want to write sequentially? Is this simply a question of interest?

Comment: Do you need the two threads to alternate? Or do you need any number of threads, and this example happens to be two?

Comment: I woud like blocked thread and wait it in acces to conslole.It is only simple example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's a rather useless question I fear, because if we want a sequential ordering threads are rather useless, but oh well, here's one solution: Assume we have N threads.

Thread 0 should write number 0, N, 2N, 3N,..

Thread 1 should write number 1, N+1, 2N+1, 3N+1

well you get the pattern. How to do this? Simple enough, we basically just need a method that waits until it's our turn to write. The real simple solution with static objects for simplicity:

```
private static volatile int globalVal = 0;
private static Object lock = new Object();

public void writeInt(int val) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while (globalVal != val) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println(val);
        globalVal++;
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

the logic in the threads itself is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Queue<String>` and add the `String`s to the queue. Then have a dedicated thread taking from the queue and writing it to the console. This will create a FIFO ordering based on the queue access of the threads.

If you don't want to use queues, you should something like a token manager that switches through the blocked threads. An `Exchanger<V>`for each participating thread would be a good starting point.

Comment: This won't ensure that sequential numbers are written to the console. The exercise is strict alternation between threads, with each waiting on the other thread in between printing.

Comment: Depends on the queue implementation, but in case of 2 threads, this could be done using `SynchronousQueue<E>`

Comment: user949300: Nope, because you can't be sure of the thread scheduling.

Comment: Touche - good point.  I think the code will need a lock that knows how to strictly alternate between threads.